# C Programming, Sorting array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

What am I doing wrong? the program run but the output isn't in the right order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () { /*program to ask user to input array values and sort them in ascending order.*/
    int n,j,i,temp;
    printf ("how many numbers?\n");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf ("enter number");
        scanf ("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++); {
     for (j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if (a[i]>a[j]){
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp; }
    } }
    printf("The numbers arranged in ascending order are given below \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Because you didn't indent your code you never saw that you have a stray `;` immediately after `for (i=0;i<n;i++); {`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++); {
```

To

```
for (i=0;i<n-1;i++) {
```

Semicolon was executed instead of following błock {}

Comment: Minor: your nested loop starts j From i+1 so clipping i by 1 let inner loop on j execute at least once even for last iteration on i

Comment: I think no need to do this. because its checking `j<n`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, in this small piece of code it is clearly not needed. But this is a good habbit to limit iterators to correct range. Otherwise in more complex code you could fall into serious troubles accessing data out of range of allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Element form right/end cant propagate to left, because for example first element of array can be swapped only at first check with second element.